# How to make a countdown until fish bites in fishing game unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a fishing game where you cast your line and it either makes unity freeze forever or it catches the fish instantly can someone help fix this. I am trying to make it so when timerToBite is greater than or equal to timerBeforeBite it will allow you to click the button which engulfs the whole screen to catch the fish. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class FishingManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody Floater;
    public Transform poleEnd;
    public Button CastButton;
    bool Casted = false;
    bool isFishing = false;
    bool fishOnLine = false;
    float timerToBite;
    float timeBeforeBite;
    float timeFloat;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() { }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() { }

    public void Cast()
    {
        Casted = !Casted;
        Debug.Log("Casted = " + Casted);
        if (Casted == true)
        {
            Rigidbody clone;
            clone = Instantiate(Floater, poleEnd.position, poleEnd.rotation) as Rigidbody;
            isFishing = true;
            Fish();
        }
        else
        {
            if (fishOnLine == false)
            {
                Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("Floater"));
                isFishing = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("Floater"));
                CatchFish();
                fishOnLine = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void CatchFish()
    {
        Debug.Log("You Caught A Fish");
    }

    void Fish()
    {
        timeBeforeBite = UnityEngine.Random.Range(50f, 100f);
        timerToBite += Time.deltaTime;
        while (isFishing == true)
        {
            if (timerToBite >= timeBeforeBite)
            {
                Debug.Log("Reel Now!");
                fishOnLine = true;
                isFishing = false;
                timerToBite = 0f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a lot of things but nothing is working. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It's worth adding the lots of things you tried and formatting your code like it's going to hang on yo' mom's fridge.

Comment: Please show us the lots of things you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's freezing because you are getting stuck in the while-loop. You should instead use a coroutine.

```
if (Casted == true)
{
    Rigidbody clone;
    clone = Instantiate(Floater, poleEnd.position, poleEnd.rotation) as Rigidbody;

    isFishing = true;
    StartCoroutine(Fish()); // start coroutine here
}
```

```
IEnumerator Fish()
{
    timeBeforeBite = UnityEngine.Random.Range(50f, 100f);

    while (isFishing == true)
    {
        if (timerToBite >= timeBeforeBite)
        {
            Debug.Log("Reel Now!");
            fishOnLine = true;
            isFishing = false;
            timerToBite = 0f;
        }
        timerToBite += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null; // return within the while-loop
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(isFishing)` and `if(Casted)` will suffice.

Comment: For didactic purposes I believe the current code is better. And you comment, as well.

Comment: I popped the timerToBite increment to inside the while loop.

Comment: thank you so much this works exactly how I want it to